# Incoming ajax data and "if" conditionals...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Fairly new to coding, so sorry if this is basic...

I'm working on a web app where clicking a "Search" button fires off an ajax request to get a bunch of data, which is then used to populate a table using the jQuery .DataTable method.

What I'm trying to do is get that same search button click event to display either one link or another, depending on what's in the returned data, on a separate part of the page.

More specifically, the search click event retrieves entries/rows that are either "bills" or "initiatives", and a single search might retrieve entries of both types (if both types exist for a given number, which is the search criterion). There is no column displayed on the table specifying which type an entry is, but that information should be part of the object returned from the ajax call (I think?); each entry has a field called "request_type" that has "B" for bill, "I" for initiative.

If the user searches on a number that has initiative entries, I want a link to the information about the initiative to pop up outside the table in a different div.  If the number has bill entries, a different link should pop up. If it's both, then two links should pop up - one for each.

I understand that ultimately, I want a conditional like

```
if (???something saying initiatives and bills are in the returned data???) {

$('#url1Div').html("<a href='" + newURL1 + "' target='_blank'>View bill information</a>");

$('#url2Div').html("<a href='" + newURL2 + "' target='_blank'>View initiative information</a>");

} else if (???just initiatives?? {

$('#url2Div').html("<a href='" + newURL2 + "' target='_blank'>View initiative information</a>");

} else if (???just bills???) {

$('#url1Div').html("<a href='" + newURL1 + "' target='_blank'>View bill information</a>");

};
```

I just don't know what those conditionals should look like given that I'm trying to work with a returning datatable object.

At first I was trying to just read information from one of the columns of the displayed table's markup, like

```
var initiativeExists;

$('#table tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
                            var texttocheck = this.innerText.trim();
                            if (texttocheck.includes("I")) {                            
                                initiativeExists = true;
                                return false;
                            } 
                            return false;
                        });
```

Then, my conditionals were just set to some version of if (initiativeExists) {//do the thing}.  But, this didn't work until the table was already populated, and it seems messy to be trying to read something from the markup when I should have the raw data to work with.

Soo....

I'm just missing some way of waiting for the data to return, then performing a check to see if any of the entries are of type "I".

Any help appreciated, will clarify as best I can. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a separate AJAX request for pulling the data so you can perform the additional logic that you want. Then assign the results into a variable so you can pass it to the datatable, assuming if this is the very same datatable library that you're using https://datatables.net/manual/data/.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly what you meant by creating a separate AJAX request, but actually, you did help by encouraging me to just go back to the beginning of the manual! lol  That is indeed the datatable library I was using.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by writing a separate callback function with the link display logic, then utilizing the "initComplete" option for .DataTable(). I used the same callback function in the part of my code that calls ajax.reload().